# how do I use my motion tracking data (face track) and apply that to a MHX2 rig already applied bvh mocap?

Tags: tracking, makehuman, motion-capture

I have tracked my face using motion tracking and linked empties to track.  i would like to apply this data to the face keys of the MHX2 makehuman (which will have its own bvh from carnegie melon) - problem is that they dont sync well because the Makehuman must be on the same plane as the motion tracks...

i was thinking if there is a way to export the motion tracked data or convert it to bvh / and / or link it to the BVH hacker to add it to exisitng BVH files ?

can anyone please advise if i am going about this the right way? my objective is to have facial tracking to animate my MHX2 makehuman and use carnegie melon BVH simultaneously? is it possible or is there another way?